# How to export only selected rows in excel? VUEYE DATA TABLE

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Greeting. I created a table and a use plugin for the VUEYE DATA TABLE. 
I want to export only selected rows(checkbox) to excel.
I also want all checkbox to be selected in the beginning.
I read the documentation but didn't find a solution.
Look my code:

```
mounted() { 
    this.axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/mytable").then(res=>{
       this.todos=res.data;
    })
}

    getChecked(rows){ 
  //only selected rows come out in the console and this is good but how to exprot only this?
  console.log("row" , rows);
},


 <vueye-table
 checkable
 tableStyle="bordered"
 :theme="theme3"
 :per-page-values="[5,10,25,50]"
 title="TODOS"
 :rows_data="todos"
 v-on:checked-rows="getChecked"
 v-on:row-click="onrowclick"
></vueye-table>
```